# GridView element selection has different size

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-gridview

I've a GridView with three columns and a fixed height.
Everything seems to be fine but when I click on an element, the selector is bigger than the clicked element.
In the image, as you can see, the fifth element is selected, and the selection goes over the elemen boundaries.

[image]

The GridView layout is pretty simple

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

and also the item is pretty straightforward

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/row_height"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/r1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do not fix the height and width of your gridview's custom view.

Comment: Its the default behaviour, remove the onclick and write custom code to highlight

Comment: @Goofy why is this? Which is the sense of a bigger selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you are using and old android theme on that activity
Try using an holo theme (@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar) and check if that solve your problem, it should.

Comment: Incredible to say but it was this. I was using a Theme.Light.NoActionBar instead of Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar !